# How do I access my android files using ADB from recovery mode?

Tags: android, adb, boot

My android (Realme GT2) has entered a bootloop, just showing the startup Realme logo, turning off and repeating. Entering recovery mode and selecting Reboot does not fix the issue. I am trying to avoid simply wiping the data so I have setup ADB with universal drivers and I am trying to transfer some files to my PC before wiping the device.

Because I cannot turn on developer mode on the device because I cannot get beyond the startup screen, I cannot get the ADB to recognise my device.

Is there any way access the files from here?

I tried using the Android SDK Tools at this link: https://www.xda-developers.com/install-adb-windows-macos-linux/

With the universal drivers from here: https://adb.clockworkmod.com/

I was hoping to have the device available to work with using the ADB despite only having access to recovery mode but have had no luck.

Comment: Stock recovery usually only provides the adb sideload command to flash a firmware image. To my knowledge, only a few custom recovery ROMs allow file access via adb. Are you talking about user data files? In such a case you need a recovery ROM that in addition supports user data decryption because user data is stored always encrypted on Android devices released for many years.

Comment: I was hoping to recover some user data files before wiping data.

Answer (score 0):

Try 1: Boot your device into recovery mode, then check if there is any option to enable debugging mode (This option was based on device OEM)

Try 2: Boot your device into fastboot mode (This option was based on device OEM), then check with `fastboot devices` command, eventhough fastboot was different from recovery mode, there is a chance that PC may detect your device in fastboot mode.

If none of these worked, then no other solution left other then wipe, at least for my knowledge.

Comment: Fastboot never offers adb commands. Fastboot and adb modes are two independent and distinct modes.

Answer (score 0):

Verify ADB Installation:

Ensure that ADB is properly installed on your computer.
Open a command prompt or terminal window on your computer and navigate to the directory where ADB is installed.
USB Debugging (if possible):

Even though you mentioned you can't enable Developer Mode, it's worth trying to see if USB Debugging was enabled before the bootloop.
Connect your phone to your computer and see if it's recognized by ADB. You can check by running the command adb devices.
Check ADB Connection:

After connecting your phone in recovery mode, run the command adb devices. If your device is not listed, there may be an issue with the ADB drivers.
Install Correct Drivers:

Make sure you have the correct USB drivers for your Realme GT2 installed on your computer. Sometimes, specific device drivers are needed.
ADB Sideload:

If your device supports ADB sideload in recovery mode, you may use this feature to push files to your device.
Boot your device into recovery mode and choose the "Apply update from ADB" option.
On your computer, run the command: adb sideload <filename.zip> where <filename.zip> is the name of the file you want to transfer.
External SD Card:

If your device has an external SD card, you might be able to remove it and use an SD card reader to access your files on another device.
Manufacturer's Support:

Check if Realme has any specific tools or procedures for data recovery or flashing firmware.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, unfortunately I tried several drivers and none worked and my device does not support ADB sideload without developer mode having been turned on.